# Text search - filter two words in two different objects/arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularJS for my webapp and I have the following problem. When I use [angularjs' filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to search for, let's say "John Smith", my object, which is built as follow ({firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Smith'}), won't be recognized because the first name and the last name are not part of the same key.

Any idea how to make the space to be either a space or a search in other keys (or arrays)?

Comment: fastest way would be to add a `fullname` to each object

Comment: This is not a good answer, I gave you an example but my object is full of that!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Per your requirements, I came up with this:

```
$scope.compFunc = function(actual, expected) {

    var expectedSplit = expected.split(' ');
    var fullActual;
    //Search people for the person the name belongs to
    $scope.names.forEach(function(person){
        angular.forEach(person, function(name){
            if (name === actual) {
                fullActual = person;
            }
        })

    })

    //create an array from the names object for comparison
    var fullActualArray = [];
    angular.forEach(fullActual, function(name, key){
        if (key != '$$hashKey')
            fullActualArray.push(name = name.toLowerCase());  
    })

    fullActualArray.sort();
    expectedSplit.sort();

    return actual.toLowerCase().indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) > -1|| 
           fullActualArray.join(',') === expectedSplit.join(',');


};
```

This should work just how you expect.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4YF6h/5/)

Note: I used `forEach` for the sake of clarity, but if you have large amounts of data you may want to change it to `for` loops, which are 90% faster and can break when a match is found.

---

**Previous solutions:**

It's very simple, checks if either the value entered in the search (`expected`) exists in either firstname or lastname (`actual`), or the opposite. So entering "Robert Downy" should work, but so will "Robert blargh" or "abcDownyefg". Checking against the whole thing (firstname + lastname) is something that you have to do outside the comparison function, and is not supported out of the box with angular as far as I know.

I've also used the following to create a new array for comparison using the full names:

```
$scope.fullnames = $scope.names.map(function(name){
    return {
        firstname: name.firstname,
        lastname: name.lastname,
        fullname :name.firstname + " " + name.lastname
    } 
})
```

While extending the original array can be done like this:

```
$scope.names.forEach(function(name){
     angular.extend(name,{fullname:name.firstname + " " + name.lastname});
})
```

This is simple and effective, and is what I would do.

Comment: Thanks Mosho, it helped me a lot but I'm still looking for a more generic solution. Let's say my object is not consistent and can have different keys or array from one object to another... I've found a solution though but it is not very efficient. My solution would be to split the search and use as many angular's filter ($filter('filter')) as I write words in my search. I can then compare my results. The problem is that it is not efficient for long text search... any suggestion?

Comment: I'm sticking with angular's filter because it has a full recursive search... if you have another way of doing it, I would be happy to hear.

Comment: Itried you fiddle but if you write robert downy you don't get it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09), and have it search whatever you want.

Comment: Is there a way not to re-invent the wheel? Is it possible to modify the existing one? If yes, how would you suggest to do it?

Comment: It's not re-inventing anything. That's the beauty of AngularJS. look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/cKN8L/.